# Numbers in network interfaces names

Tags: linux, network-interface

I am working now with a Linux-based system, that has several network interfaces according to ifconfig. Some of them have strange naming, e.g. **eth0:1** or **eth0.2**.

What might this kind of naming (with a second number) mean about the purpose of the corresponding interfaces? Are they standard for some particular networking configurations in Linux or is it manually assigned by the system administrator/engineer? How would one begin to investigate on their purpose?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=eth0%3A1

Comment: When you see eth0:1,eth0:2 that virtual interface of First Ethernet interface.The interface number started from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Those names correspond to network subinterfaces, that is, the logical division of physical interfaces.

You can create them in the same way that you create any interface in /etc/network/interfaces (or the corresponding file for your distribution), so eth0:1 means the first network subinterface of network interface eth0, eth0:2 the second network subinterface of network interface eth0 and so on...

By searching in Google for "Linux network subinterfaces" you will find a lot of information about it.

Comment: This.  Also be aware that network device names have been changing in recent releases of many different distros